# IE 8 not picking up CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I've included a conditional comment for an IE 8 stylesheet, which seems to be working, but my basic bootstrap styles are not.  Seems like IE 8 ignores bootstrap grid and makes everything expand the width of the page.

BTW - I only have basic front-end skills.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question so we can try to help with your issue.

Comment: Sorry - I included a link to the site but it got stripped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 requires a polyfill for media queries. Use Scott Jehl's awesome plugin: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond
This should go AFTER your CSS calls in the head.

Comment: additionally, make sure you check the bootstrap's docs, as there are certain features from Bootstrap that just won't work with IE8.  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started#support

Comment: This got me on the right direction.  I imported the 992px wide media queries into the IE stylesheet and that seemed to work.  Thanks!